FTDI USB serial tty ID Locking on ubuntu 20.04.6
/dev/TTYUSB0 is discarded after disconnecting and reconnecting an FTDI 232 UART.
When reconnected, it now has incremented to /dev/TTYUSB1
I haven't tried multiple disconnects, yet.  The hardware is in a remote facility several towns away.
From lsusb:
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0403:6001 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT232 Serial (UART) IC
Is there a way to lock the ID/enumeration to always create /dev/ttyUSB0 when that particular device is connected to that particular port?  We have several machines running, and if a service technician has to disconnect / reconnect an external device, the FTDI UART is disconnected for a minute or two before being reconnected.
A reboot solves this, of course, but we'd like to avoid system down time, so a soft solution would be MUCH better.  Even if I could somehow manually force the driver to move from USB1 to USB0 post-reconnect, that would also work OK.
Using a symlink is not a viable solution, as the manufacturer's software is hard-coded to use ttyUSB0.
